# How to migrate Artifactory binarystore from file-system to sharding?

Tags: migration, artifactory, sharding

We have an Artifactory 7.55.9 and our binarystory.xml is:

```
<config version="v1">
    <chain template="file-system"/>
    <provider id="file-system" type="file-system">
        <baseDataDir>/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data</baseDataDir>
        <fileStoreDir>data</fileStoreDir>
        <tempDir>tmp</tempDir>
    </provider>
</config>
```

Free disk space has run out.
We can't resize it.

We added second disk, created partition and filesystem.

Can we change binarystore.xml without export/import binaries?
Will this configuration work?

```
<config version="4">
    <chain>
        <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
             <provider id="sharding" type="sharding">
                  <sub-provider id="disk1" type="state-aware"/>
                  <sub-provider id="disk2" type="state-aware"/>
             </provider>
        </provider>
    </chain>

    <provider id="sharding" type="sharding">
         <readBehavior>roundRobin</readBehavior>
         <writeBehavior>percentageFreeSpace</writeBehavior>
         <redundancy>1</redundancy>
    </provider>

//For each sub-provider (mount), specify the filestore location

    <provider id="disk1" type="state-aware">
         <fileStoreDir>/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/data</fileStoreDir>
    </provider>

    <provider id="disk2" type="state-aware">
         <fileStoreDir>/disk2/artifactory/shard-fs-2</fileStoreDir>
    </provider>

</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct. You do not need to perform System Export and Import. Once after making the changes, restart Artifactory so that the changes in binary store will be reflected.
Please visit this below two pages.
https://jfrog.com/help/r/switching-from-nfs-to-sharding-cluster
and
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/optimize-system-storage
If you face any difficulty, you are welcome to get back here.